# C# to VB.Net Syntax conversion

Tags: vb.net

Can any one translate the following syntax to vb.net.

```
m_TextBox.Loaded += TextBoxLoaded
m_TextBox.Loaded -= TextBoxLoaded;
private void TextBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   Init();
 }

..
containsTextProp.AddValueChanged(m_TextBox, (sender, args) => UpdateAdorner());
...
private void UpdateAdorner()
        {...}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here it is:

```
AddHandler m_TextBox.Loaded, AddressOf TextBoxLoaded
RemoveHandler m_TextBox.Loaded, AddressOf TextBoxLoaded

Private Sub TextBoxLoaded(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as RoutedEventArgs)
    Init()
End Sub
```

Your call to `AddValueChanged` can't be directly translated, as VB.NET's lambda expression support is not as robust as C#'s. In particular, VB.NET lambdas must be an expression, so you must either return a value or call a `Function`. In your case, you would be calling a `Sub`, which isn't allowed in VB.NET. You should consider changing the signature of `UpdateAdorner` to be a standard event handler (like the `TextBoxLoaded` method) and pass `AddressOf UpdateAdoerner` to `AddValueChanged`.

Like this:

```
containsTextProp.AddValueChanged(m_TextBox, AddressOf UpdateAdorner);

...

Private Sub UpdateAdorner(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs)
    ... 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of [online converters](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/), you shuold probably try that first next time and post here if it doesn't work or you have a problem.

```
AddHandler m_TextBox.Loaded, AddressOf TextBoxLoaded     ' per @Adam Robinson'
RemoveHandler m_TextBox.Loaded, AddressOf TextBoxLoaded  ' per @Adam Robinson'

Private Sub TextBoxLoaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
  Init()
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateAdorner()

End Sub
```

Comment: i tried Developer Fusion's Converter and Telerik converter.. converted code is giving me compile time errors... like use RaiseEvent ... new to vb.net ..so asked here...

Comment: Events in VB.NET use `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler`, not the operator syntax of C# as you have here.

Comment: getting compile time errors with above syntax.. using Adam's syntax... anyway thanx for the replay and +1

Comment: @Adam, see I just used the converter and didn't notice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might find the "C# and VB.NET Comparison Cheat Sheet" useful.
http://aspalliance.com/625

Answer (score 1):

You can toss it in an app, build it, then open the app in .NET reflector. .NET Reflector can take the IL and "turn it into" C#/VB.NET, etc.